# Writing custom Content Provider for photos on phone

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

As part of a course on Android app development, I need to write my own ContentProvider. The app I'm making is a simple (? not so sure anymore) photo gallery app, with a master activity showing thumbnails in a GridView, and a detail activity showing one selected image along with some meta data. I've got something working by simply querying the MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails and Images, but -- as I said -- I need + want to learn how to "roll my own" CP.

But! Every tutorial I find deals with interfacing/querying the SQLite database. What I need is to query a directory, a set of files (JPEGs). It really makes NO sense to first dump all photos into the database, only to make the CP-part "easier" (meaning: follow some SQL-CP tutorial).

So: anyone want to help me build a CP for this? Not asking for someone to "do my homework" (btw, this is a free Android course on Udacity -- not school stuff), but I need some advice and pointers in the right direction. I was thinking I'd post what I've got so far, and hopefully someone will comment! The "template" I'm following, is the WeatherContract and [WeatherProvider from the Udacity course's "Sunshine" app](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/sunshine_master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/data) (which uses SQLite, obviously).

### URIs

First: The URIs I want to support. It occurs to me I need two "types": **thumbnails** and **images**. For each of these, it should be possible to provide a **path** to a specific folder, and why not let the user *filter* on something -- say -- **year** (DATE_TAKEN). Finally, except for thumbnails, the user can specify a specific image to load in the detail activity. Since this is not a database, we have no "image IDs", so I guess we need to rely on **filename** here?

Here are the URIs I envision (AUTH is just some authority for my app):

1. `content://AUTH/thumb` gives all *thumbnails* on phone (i.e., equals `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` ?)
2. `content://AUTH/thumb/path/*` gives all photos in specified directory (the path will have to be URI-encoded, right, such that `/` becomes `%2F`)
3. `content://AUTH/thumb/year/#` and `content://AUTH/thumb/path/*/year/#` is same as above, but filtered on year
4. `content://AUTH/photos` gives all *photos* on phone (`MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`)
5. `content://AUTH/photos/year/#`
6. `content://AUTH/photos/year/#` and `content://AUTH/photos/path/*/year/#`
7. finally, `content://AUTH/photos/path/*/img/*` gives a (one) specific image (based on filename, for lack of numerical unique ID)

### The "Contract"

With those URIs in mind, what would the PhotoContract look like? I'll post the code I've got so far as a comment below, and update it as I work on it.

### The Content Provider

For the implementation (PhotoProvider extends ContentProvider), I guess there are two approaches: Either open a File reader to list *.jpg from the specificed directory/path, dump these into a MatrixCursor, and return. Alternatively, and maybe simpler, would be to simply get a cursor from MediaStore (Thumbnails or Images, depending on URI) and just return that? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Follow-up post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700680/writing-custom-content-provider-for-photos-on-phone-part-2